# rails installation from http://installrails.com/ - undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, git-bash

Hi i am tryng to installs rails for the first time, following steps given in http://installrails.com/. But I am facing this problem when I give this command in git bash

```
curl http://installrails.com/update_rubygems.rb | ruby
```

this error comes up:

```
Downloading ...
-:55:in 'filename': undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass <NoMethodError>
     from -:25:in 'download'
     from -:14:in 'call'
     from -:60:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Which Ruby are are you using? (`ruby -v`).

Also maybe don't use git bash, and visit this page for instructions on rails installation: http://guides.railsgirls.com/install#setup-for-linux

Comment: thanks man,  guides.railsgirls.com it worked.